# Is this a good design for a table?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

Each user/person could know one or more languages.

All I can think is a table like

```
+----------+------+-----+------------+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| PersonID | Java | PHP | Javascript | C++ |  C  | CSS | HTML  |
+----------+------+-----+------------+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|        1 | Yes  | Yes | No         | Yes | No  | Yes | No    |
|        2 | No   | Yes | Yes        | No  | Yes | No  | No    |
|        3 | Yes  | No  | Yes        | Yes | Yes | Yes | No    |
+----------+------+-----+------------+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Considering I'm going to need at least 100 columns for all the languages, is it normal to have that many columns? Something tells me this is the wrong approach.

Thank you very much and sorry about my english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to create three tables.

One table contains the information of the Person like his Name etc.

Second table contains two columns LanguageId and Language name.

```
+------------+-----------+
| LanguageID | Name      |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          | Javascript| 
| 2          | C         | 
| 3          | C++       | 
+------------+-----------+
```

Third table contains the Id, PersonId, LanguageID. In this table you can join the above two tables record.

```
+---+----------+------------+
|ID | PersonID | LanguageID | 
+---+----------+------------+
|1  |        1 | 1          | 
|2  |        2 | 2          | 
|3  |        3 | 3          | 
+---+----------+------------+
```

Reasons to support my answer:

- In future if you want to add any new language in your table then it
  would be easier to add that in the main table.
- You can join the two tables easily and get the result

Comment: But what if PersonID 1 knows LanguageID 1 and LanguageID 2? How would you indicate that in the first table?

Comment: @anonymous:- You can create a Person table where you can add the details of  the person. And then in your table you can join the two tables.

Comment: @anonymous:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: It's helping a lot, but there is one thing I can't really comprehend. In the third table how can I indicate that a person knows language 1 and language 2? Would it be like this, repeating the person ID?

[link](http://i.snag.gy/3kZ4I.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

A little improvement we can do over Rahul Tripathi response is to remove the "Known" column. You need only two tables for this case. One containing PersonId and LanguageId the person knows. The second table is for the languages only.

You know what languages one person knows by joining both tables. For example if you need to know the list of known languages you can do:

```
SELECT p.PersonId, l.Name
FROM Person p INNER JOIN Language l ON (p.LanguageId = l.LanguageId)
WHERE (p.PersonId = theIdYouNeedToKnow)
```

Comment: Very well noted point. Thanks for pointing that flaw in the my answer. Updated that as well !